# Single Producer, Multiple Consumers with a few unusual twists

Tags: multithreading, event-handling, producer-consumer

I have a (Posix) server that acts as a proxy for many clients to another upstream server.  Messages typically flow down from the upstream server, are then matched against, and pushed out to some subset of the clients interested in that traffic (maintaining the FIFO order from the upstream server).  Currently, this proxy server is single threaded using an event loop (e.g. - select, epoll, etc.), but now I'd like to make it multithreaded so that the proxy can more fully utilize an entire machine and achieve much higher throughput.

My high level design is to have a pool of N worker pthreads (where N is some small multiple of the number of cores on the machine) who each run their own event loop.  Each client connection will be assigned to a specific worker thread who would then be responsible for servicing all of that client's I/O + timeout needs for the duration of that client connection.  I also intend to have a single dedicated thread who pulls in the messages in from the upstream server.  Once a message is read in, its contents can be considered constant / unchanging, until it is no longer needed and reclaimed.  The workers never alter the message contents -- they just pass them along to their clients as needed.

My first question is: should the matching of client interests preferably be done by the producer thread or the worker threads?

In the former approach, for each worker thread, the producer could check the interests (e.g. - group membership) of the worker's clients.  If the message matched any clients, then it could push the message onto a dedicated queue for that worker.  This approach requires some kind of synchronization between the producer and each worker about their client's rarely changing interests.

In the latter approach, the producer just pushes every message onto some kind of queue shared by all of the worker threads.  Then each worker thread checks **ALL** of the messages for a match against their clients' interests and processes each message that matches.  This is a twist on the usual SPMC problem where a consumer is usually assumed to unilaterally *take* an element for themselves, rather than all consumers needing to do some processing on every element.  This approach distributes the matching work across multiple threads, which seems desirable, but I worry it *may* cause more contention between the threads depending on how we implement their synchronization.

In both approaches, when a message is no longer needed by any worker thread, it then needs to be reclaimed.  So, some tracking needs to be done to know when no worker thread needs a message any longer.

My second question is: what is a good way of tracking whether a message is still needed by any of the worker threads?

A simple way to do this would be to assign to each message a count of how many worker threads still need to process the message when it is first produced.  Then, when each worker is done processing a message it would decrement the count in a thread-safe manner and if/when the count went to zero we would know it could be reclaimed.

Another way to do this would be to assign 64b sequence numbers to the messages as they came in, then each thread could track and record the highest sequence number up through which they have processed somehow.  Then we could reclaim all messages with sequence numbers less than or equal to the minimum processed sequence number across all of the worker threads in some manner.

The latter approach seems like it could more easily allow for a lazy reclamation process with less cross-thread synchronization necessary.  That is, you could have a "clean-up" thread that only runs periodically who goes and computes the minimum across the worker threads, with much less inter-thread synchronization being necessary.  For example, if we assume that reads and writes of a 64b integer are atomic and a worker's fully processed sequence number is always monotonically increasing, then the "clean-up" thread can just periodically read the workers' fully processed counts (maybe with some memory barrier) and compute the minimum.

Third question: what is the best way for workers to realize that they have new work to do in their queue(s)?

Each worker thread is going to be managing its own event loop of client file descriptors and timeouts.  Is it best for each worker thread to just have their own pipe to which signal data can be written by the producer to poke them into action?  Or should they just periodically check their queue(s) for new work?  Are there better ways to do this?

Last question: what kind of data structure and synchronization should I use for the queue(s) between the producer and the consumer?

I'm aware of lock-free data structures but I don't have a good feel for whether they'd be preferable in my situation or if I should instead just go with a simple mutex for operations that affect the queue.  Also, in the shared queue approach, I'm not entirely sure how a worker thread should track "where" it is in processing the queue.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: What is currently limiting your throughput?  If it's limited by network bandwidth, for example, using multiple threads isn't going to help.  If it's limited by processing, what are the compute intensive parts of your current software?

Comment: @WarrenDew It's CPU bound on a single core (e.g. - showing 100% CPU on one core in top).  The single threaded proxy, as it is, can push between 600Mb/s to 1Gb/s (on a 10Gb/s NIC and network) out depending on the particulars of the traffic.  I'm not 100% sure which particular piece is eating the most CPU.  The most intensive part **should** be sending the traffic to the client.  Right now, I'm just trying to get some simple parallelism so I can utilize more of the machine, which has 8 cores.  If I can get a 2-4x speedup, then that would be great for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your problem description, matching of client interests needs to be done for each client for each message anyway, so the work in matching is the same whichever type of thread it occurs in.  That suggests the matching should be done in the client threads to improve concurrency.  Synchronization overhead should not be a major issue if the "producer" thread ensures the messages are flushed to main memory (technically, "synchronize memory with respect to other threads") before their availability is made known to the other threads, as the client threads can all read the information from main memory simultaneously without synchronizing with each other.  The client threads will not be able to modify messages, but they should not need to.

Message reclamation is probably better done by tracking the current message number of each thread rather than by having a message specific counter, as a message specific counter presents a concurrency bottleneck.

I don't think you need formal queueing mechanisms.  The "producer" thread can simply keep a volatile variable updated which contains the number of the most recent message that has been flushed to main memory, and the client threads can check the variable when they are free to do work, sleeping if no work is available.  You could get more sophisticated on the thread management, but the additional efficiency improvement would likely be minor.

I don't think you need sophisticated data structures for this.  You need volatile variables for the number of the latest message that is available for processing and for the number of the most recent message that have been processed by each client thread.  You need to flush the messages themselves to main memory.  You need some way of finding the messages in main memory from the message number, perhaps using a circular buffer of pointers, or of messages if the messages are all of the same length.  You don't really need much else with respect to the data to be communicated between the threads.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  Can you be more specific about what you mean when you say I need to "flush the messages ... to main memory?"  I'm using high level interfaces (e.g. - pthreads) and would prefer not to use any kind of assembler code or anything like that.

Comment: I believe pthreads refers to it as "synchronize memory with respect to other threads".  Here's a discussion of pthreads memory synchronization with a list of functions that can be used:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12